# Fixed div outside of parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I am currently working on converting a website from a static desktop layout to a more mobile friendly design. I am currently converting a sidebar of content into a fullscreen modal type window but I am having the current problem. Can you position a fixed div (child of the sidebar element) on top of the entire body, i.e. as a direct descendant of the body.

I am tearing my hair out over this, the only success I am having is by cloning the element and putting it as a child of the body element.

Comment: yes you can.. but cant help without seeing the actual code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** If the path from your fixed element up to `<body>` does not contain any `position:absolute` containers, then your fixed element will be placed ontop of all other. Assuming no other elements with a higher `z-index` are rendered ontop that is.

If, on the other hand, any container is absolute positioned, the fixed element will take that as the relative parent.

**Note:** This is the default behaviour. It may vary depending on your markup. But without any code example it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction :) I didn't post the code as I only wanted suggestions on how I could possibly be going wrong. I wanted to attempt a fix myself. x